# Need a logic in to get elements

Tags: java, collections

I am new to programming and I need a logic for below

service contains (This is a list)

```
XX04|N|abc.02
XX04|N|abc.03
XX04|N|xyz.03
XX04|N|xyz.02
XX04|N|deg.01

entry Map contains 

abc.def.01-abc.02
abc.def.01-xyz.02
abc.max.01-xyz.01

 for(String test: entry.getValue()){
   if(Service.contains(test){
     //Logic here to take only those services(Like 
     XX04|N|abc.02
     XX04|N|xyz.02
     XX04|N|deg.01       
 }
```

Comment: It is not sure what are the actual contents of the list or the map. For example for the map what or `abc.def.01-abc.02` is the key and what the value or is it just the value for some key?

Comment: @Ackdari: abc.def.01-abc.02 are values for some keys which I will get through entry.getValue()

Comment: and how does the string `abc.def.01-abc.02` relate to any of the services? I mean in the string `abc.max.01-xyz.01` what does `max` mean?

Comment: @Ackdari: what does max mean? - This is just a naming convention it does not mean anything.
abc.def.01-abc.02 relate to any of the services? - If you look at -abc.02 in abc.def.01-abc.02 this relates abc.02 to XX04|N|abc.02 so like wise xyz.02 in abc.def.01-xyz.02 relates to xyz.02 in XX04|N|xyz.02 and so on.

Comment: how should the service `XX04|N|deg.01` be choosen, because there seems no entry related to it.

Comment: it will not choose that since i am giving as .contains, it will skip that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upfront I would suggest modeling this not with only string but object that contain some getter methods for some id.

I know will make the assumtion that the content of the map is always matches to the regex

```
\w*\.\w*\.\d*-\w*\.\d*
```

and the services are always matches to

```
\w*\d*\|N\|[A-z0-9.]*
```

Then you can use Regular expressions to extract the id part of the strings using a named capturing group.

```java
Pattern servicePattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*\\d*\\|N\\|(?<id>\\w*\\.\\d*)");
Pattern entryPattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*\\.\\w*\\.\\d*-(?<id>\\w*\\.\\d*)");

for (String name : entry.getValue()) {
    Matcher entryMatcher = entryPattern.matcher(name);
    Assume.true(entryMatcher.matches());

    String id = entryMatcher.group("id");

    for (String serviceName : Service) {
        Matcher serviceMatcher = servicePattern.matcher();
        if (serviceMatcher.matches()) {
            if (id.equals(serviceMatcher.group("id"))) {
                // do what ever you want with the service
            }
        }
    }
}
```